# Join table on specific condition SQL

Tags: sql

I have table A and B.

I want to basically join Table B to table A only if it meets certain conditions (otherwise display NULL). Table A has the transaction recorded and Table B has the actual username that recorded that transaction **if** it was an external user.

Unfortunately, my idea on how to make this possible either 1) exclude results where it was made by an internal user 2) throw a conversion failed error because internal users don't exist in Table B AND are in a different format for that column being joined.

The joined column (application name) has Internal users with 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query' but external users have '674d9234206-3p57-3453-8935-8641dufwhaih20f9' which Table B has.

This query gives me the conversion error:

```
select TableB.userid,TableA.*
left outer join TableB on cast(TableB.TransactionId as varchar(36)) = TableA.ApplicationName
```

This query excludes my internal user from the results:

```
select TableB.userid,TableA.*
join TableB on cast(TableB.TransactionId as varchar(36)) = TableA.ApplicationName
```

I would want the userid column to display from Table B if it was an external user, otherwise default to NULL or the column indicating INTERNAL_USER.  Is this even possible? I think I read something about coalesce but I don't know how to use it when the join isn't even possible.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I only need 1 column from Table B which is the user_id (Integer). The join column applicationname in Table A is nvchar128 in format of 74d9234206-3p57-3453-8935-8641dufwhaih20f9 or Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query. The corresponding table B column is PK uniqidentifer not null (I dont' see a type other than that for it) but it's also format 74d9234206-3p57-3453-8935-8641dufwhaih20f9.

Answer (score 0):

My coworker helped me with this solution:

I guess the `userid` being pulled in was a integer so I couldn't put in
else `A.Username` which was not an integer.

```
Select top 1000
case when A.UserName ='EXTERNAL_USER' then B.userid else '999999' end [userid]
  ah.*
From Table A as A with (nolock)
left outer join Table B as B  (nolock) on  A.ApplicationName = cast(B.TransactionId as varchar(36))
```